# Place a GtkMenu in the middle of an application , instead of always showing on top area?

Tags: menu, gtk

I wanted a GtkMenuBar like widget being placed anywhere i want in the application , is that possible ? (Horizontal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just pack it into whatever container you like.